# Can't get WiFi USB adapter to work 22.04

Tags: wireless, usb, adapter

I'm trying to get my Wifi USB adapter to work but don't really know what I'm doing. `lsusb` shows

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0b05:17d2 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB-AC56 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8812AU]
```

and then there's this for what it's worth, got no idea.
[additional Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFOT0.png)

I have an ethernet connection working fine but I can't continue to use it as my main connection. I don't even see a little wifi icon in the top bar. Ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `usb-devices | awk '/17d2/' RS=` command.

Comment: The driver for your device is *8812au*. Please follow the precedure at the duplicate. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.